# How to add custom translation to Antdesign + React.js App

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am using Antd + React.js combination. Can anybody help me with how to implement Internationalization like I want to add my own translation too? I understand how the default one is working. I would like to add the translation for my own custom component.

Comment: Are you talking about the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your own custom component you probably won't be able to use internationalization that comes packed with antd components.

Your best bet would probably be a library like [react-i18next](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next) or [react-intl](https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl). Both are easy to implement and can provide you a way to put any kind of translated/formatted strings in your application, no matter what UI framework you actually use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I am going with react-intl plugin now.